# How I set an animation on the PopBackStack() function?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, fragment, fragmentmanager

On navigation from 1 fragment to another I am using slide animation.
So, when i use the `PopBackStack` function, it moves from the left to the right like i was not going back, but moving forward. I mean, when i slide the page back it slide out to left side and the "new" page slide in from right.
I want the opposite. Slide out right -> slide in left.

Because I can't set up the animation to `PopBackStack` directly, I tried to get the last fragment and call it like it was a new fragment.

```
Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction fragTx = fragmentActivity.SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                fragTx.SetCustomAnimations(inAnimation, outAnimation, inAnimation, outAnimation);
                if (addToBackStack) fragTx.AddToBackStack(null);
                fragTx.Replace(Resource.Id.MML_content_frame, fragment);
                fragTx.Commit();
```

So, I tried to get the back stack entry by using the `SupportFragmentManager`,
but despite it show me that have the right entries, the `GetBackStackEntryAt` function returns me null, so i can't get the name from the Fragment.

```
if (this.Activity.SupportFragmentManager.BackStackEntryCount == 0)
{
    return null;
}
String fragmentTag = Activity.SupportFragmentManager.GetBackStackEntryAt(Activity.SupportFragmentManager.BackStackEntryCount - 1).Name;
return Activity.SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);
```

Someone already had the same problem or similar?
Is there a way to specify a new animation and set it with `setCustomAnimations` function or do it directly to `PopBackStack`?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo so that we can test with it?

Comment: I just do this line of code:

`this.Activity.SupportFragmentManager.PopBackStack();`